# CP Command Can't Locate Desktop Files

Tags: ubuntu

```
sudo cp /Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43
```

I've also tried to exec this command:

```
"cp /Desktop/b43/*  /lib/firmware/b43/"
```

From the root and I get the same answer, `file not found`.

```
root@candice-Aspire-3690:/home/candice# ls -ir
1048602 Videos     1048598 Public    1048596 Downloads
1048597 Templates  1048601 Pictures  1048599 Documents
1048716 snap       1048600 Music     1048595 Desktop
```

The name of my user account is candice.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is get internet access on my Aspire 3690-2970 laptop.

Is there an alternate way of accomplishing this task using Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Use an absolute file-address, not using `~`.

Comment: I don't use sudo when at the root level.

Comment: Show us an example that doesn't use tilde.

Comment: This is an entirely different question - you should perhaps post the root problem as a separate question. We can't troubleshoot your methods of solving the problem without knowing more about the problem itself.

Comment: Does the target directory exist?

Comment: You should just run `ls /home/candice/Desktop/b43/` to see your files, then run `cp` like you wanted, with said path. This is exactly the same path as `~/Desktop/b43/`, but since you are using `sudo`, you are using `/home/root/Desktop`, since "sudo" is running as root.

Comment: Netan:  ls: cannot access '/home/candice/Desktop/b43/': No such file or directory.  I've listed properties and cut n pasted the path in it's entirety to no avail,  This file exist on my desktop, but for some reason, the desktop can't be found.

Comment: Grawity:  yes, I created it prior to trying to copy to it.  The error msg I'm getting is complaining about not finding the Desktop.    This is what I got from properties - Name /home/candice/Desktop/ b43-fwcutter_019-7build2.debian.tar.xz Type Tar archive (XZ-compressed) (application/x-xz-compressed-tar) Size 19.8 kB (19,820 bytes) –

Comment: note, to ping people, use @ before their username, so they receive a notification that you replied to them. eg @Frank Thomas.

Comment: @Netan: ls: cannot access '/home/candice/Desktop/b43/': No such file or directory. I've listed properties and cut n pasted the path in it's entirety to no avail, This file exist on my desktop, but for some reason, the desktop can't be found.   I responded to you several hours ago, but I just found out about @ sign preceding the name, my bad...

Comment: @Grawity: I responded to you several hours ago, but I just found out about @ sign preceding the name, my bad...

Comment: @Grawity: yes, I created it prior to trying to copy to it. The error msg I'm getting is complaining about not finding the Desktop. This is what I got from properties - Name /home/candice/Desktop/ b43-fwcutter_019-7build2.debian.tar.xz Type Tar archive (XZ-compressed) (application/x-xz-compressed-tar) Size 19.8 kB (19,820 bytes)

Comment: So the error message IS correct, there's NO `b43` folder inside `Desktop` but actually a file (b43-fwc...). That said, here's a suggestion: **1. STOP!** You really don't know what you're doing and you're blindly following same random instructions you don't understand and may not be applicable. Forget about this question. **2.** In your other question (because this is all about troubleshooting the WiFi, of course) **post the required results** in order to identify your hardware **and your distro, including release/version.** Then someone might post an useful answer that actually solves it.

Answer (score 1):

The `~` (tilde) character has a special meaning, which is to address
files or directories inside your home folder.

While doing `sudo` you're changing your identity to that of root,
so the tilde is no longer your home folder.

Use instead of the tilde the absolute address of your home folder.

Comment: @Shep: Are you sure that the folder `~/Desktop` exists ?

Comment: Harry: absolutely, I put it there myself as per instructed.  I checked out the properties, then cut n pasted the entire name to no avail.  I even took off file name and it couldn't even find the Desktop, there lies the problem...

Comment: Are you doing this from the same account that owns all subfolders and files?

Comment: Harry:  This is what I got from properties - Name /home/candice/Desktop/
b43-fwcutter_019-7build2.debian.tar.xz

Type Tar archive (XZ-compressed) (application/x-xz-compressed-tar)

Size 19.8 kB (19,820 bytes)

Comment: This is hard to read. Please add the output of `ls -lR` to your post, and indicate the name of your user account.

Comment: FYI...I'm very new to Linux; actually, I'm a zOS mainframe DB2 DBA.  I'm not sure about the accounts, but installing the same OS on my desk top, I did not have this issue.

Comment: Don't add a space after the `-`. You really are new to it, I'm not sure that I can help.

Comment: As far as I know, I did nothing to change the default account in which I signed onto.

Comment: root@candice-Aspire-3690:/home/candice# ls -ir
1048602 Videos     1048598 Public    1048596 Downloads
1048597 Templates  1048601 Pictures  1048599 Documents
1048716 snap       1048600 Music     1048595 Desktop